# flutter Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [422]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API which sends status 201 in case of a success and if there's any error with the submitted data it sends status 422 (Unprocessable Entity) with a JSON response.

```
{
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "mobile": [
        "The selected mobile is invalid."
    ]
}}
```

I am using Dio to post user credentials (mobile, password) if I enter the correct user credential I can fetch data from it but when I enter the wrong credential gives me this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [422]
```

Dio code

```
    userLogin(
    String password,
    String mobile,
  ) async {
    try {
      String url = "url";

      Dio dio = Dio();

      dio.options.headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      };
      var response = await dio.post(url, queryParameters: {
        "password": password,
        "mobile": mobile,
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }}
```

How I cloud handle error response and success?

Answer (score 3):

If some of Http status codes in responses are approved then you could use validateStatus function in BaseOptions to make them valid for all dio requests.

```
Dio dio = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
      headers: {...},
      validateStatus: (statusCode){
        if(statusCode == null){
          return false;
        }
        if(statusCode == 422){ // your http status code
          return true;
        }else{
          return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;
        }
      },
    )
);
```

or validateStatus function in Options of concrete request

```
var response = await dio.post(url, 
  queryParameters: {
    "password": password,
    "mobile": mobile,
  },
  options: Options(
    responseType: ResponseType.json,
    validateStatus: (statusCode){
      if(statusCode == null){
        return false;
      }
      if(statusCode == 422){ // your http status code
        return true;
      }else{
        return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch method has to be added to the try. In your case it was added to if(response.statuscode ==200)

```
userLogin(
    String password,
    String mobile,
  ) async {
    try {
      String url = "url";

      Dio dio = Dio();

      dio.options.headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      };
      var response = await dio.post(url, queryParameters: json.encode({
        "password": password??"",
        "mobile": mobile??"",
      }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.data;
      } 
     else{
       print(response.data);
       return "request failed";
       }
     }catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
```

Comment: same Http status error [422]
when I enter wrong credential it does not execute  what its inside if (response.statusCode == 200) it jumps to catch error part

Comment: hope you are using the correct url and not the one written here.

Comment: yes I have the  right one I test it with correct mobile and password it works fine

Comment: add a print statement just above if(response.statusCode == 200) `print(response.data);`

Comment: Error 422 means that your request is correct. Its just that the server is unable to process data that you have sent. Which I think how its handled by the backend. You can check if the statusCode == 422 and return something.

Comment: so just for test I put print above and inside each of if , else and catch 
in success it print out above if and inside it but in case of wrong credential it print only the one inside catch

Comment: all ready tried  if (response.statusCode == 442) it skips this part and jump to catch

Comment: Try to jsonencode the query param edited my answer

Comment: Did json encoding the body work?

Comment: no it give me same thing

Comment: Edited my answer. Not sure if you are sending null so added a null check and sent empty strings

Comment: also it did not work

Comment: When you send incorrect data what's the body?

Answer (score 0):

My Api response was this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uJWe.jpg)

I have dealt with this method by allowing it BaseOptions
here is my post API code and bingo got the solution to problem

```
Future postApiResponse(
          String url, dynamic data, bool tokentrue, String? token) async {
        dynamic responceJson;
        try {
          // print('here 222');
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('In Dio in try');
            print(url);
            print(data.toString());
            print(tokentrue.toString());
            print(token.toString());
            print('In Dio in try');
          }
          Dio dio = Dio(BaseOptions(validateStatus: (statusCode) {
            if (statusCode == 422) {
              return true;
            }
            if (statusCode == 200) {
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }));
          if (tokentrue == true) {
            // dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
            dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
          } else {
            dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
          }
          // print('responceJson.toString()');
          Response responce = await dio
              .post(
                url,
                data: data,
              )
              .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
    
          debugPrint('.toString()');
          responceJson = returnResponce(responce);
          debugPrint(responce.toString());
        } on DioError catch (e) {
          returnExceptionError(e);
        }
    
        return responceJson;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [422]

The Solution :)

```
Dio dio = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
      headers: {...},
      validateStatus: (statusCode){
        if(statusCode == null){
          return false;
        }
        if(statusCode == 422){ // your http status code
          return true;
        }else{
          return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;
        }
      },
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//**Solution**
//Same other solutions but use new sdk version
//add this into dio instance
 validateStatus: (code) => switch (code.runtimeType) {
            int => code == 422 || '$code'.startsWith('2'),
            _ => false
          }));

//**Exception**
DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 422.
#0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:507)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1661)
#2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:174)
#3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:852)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:873)
#5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:649)
#6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:60)
#7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:26)
#8      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:620)
#9      _RootZone.runBi`enter code here`nary (dart:async/zone.dart:1666)
#10     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:171)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:852)
#12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:873)
#13     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:649)
#14     Future._chainForeignFuture.<anonymous closure> `enter code here`(dart:async/future_impl.dart:550)
#15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40)
#16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49)`enter code
```